# Cannot trap some Python DBus except errors

Tags: gnome, python, d-bus

I'm getting this error in Python which is non-fatal and I'm presuming is written to `stderr`:

> ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.4:/org/freedesktop/thermald:
>   dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
>   org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2
>   matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.974" (uid=1000 pid=20020
>   comm="/usr/bin/python ./mmm ")
>   interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member="Introspect"
>   error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.4" (uid=0
>   pid=1309 comm="/usr/sbin/thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable ")

Sorry for unorthodox "quote" instead of `code` block. I wanted to save scrolling 8 miles to the right.

I can trap the error with:

```
    except dbus.exceptions.DBusException as err:
        # Same as dbus.DBusException
        print('\ndbus.exceptions.DBusException:', service)
        print(err.message+'\n')
        return False
    except dbus.DBusException as err:
        # Same as dbus.exceptions.DBusException
        print('\ndbus.DBusException:', service)
        print(err.message+'\n')
        return False
```

However it just generates my except which is **MOST** of the previous error message. But it doesn't suppress the previous error message which normally happens???

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.thermald
Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.974" (uid=1000 pid=20020 comm="/usr/bin/python ./mmm ") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable" member="Introspect" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.4" (uid=0 pid=1309 comm="/usr/sbin/thermald --no-daemon --dbus-enable ")
```

Altogether I'm getting 4 System Service DBus "Access Denied" errors abbreviated below:

```
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.19:/fi/epitest/hostap/WPASupplicant:
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.19:/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1:
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.20:/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/dnsmasq:
ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.4:/org/freedesktop/thermald:
```

These all seem to be common Ubuntu errors (I'm on 16.04.6 LTS, kernel 4.14.170, Gnome 3.18). I have no desire to fix the errors. For my project I have no need to inspect these DBus services. I just want to suppress the error messages.

FWIW I"m also getting two Session Service DBUS errors that I **can** successfully trap:

```
==============   Session services   ================

Object path: '/org/freedesktop/network-manager-applet' contains invalid character '-'
Object path: '/org/nautilus-actions/DBus' contains invalid character '-'
```

I think from this [post](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html) they might have to be escaped, eg `\-`. What the errors really mean and how to fix them would be nice too.

FWIW again here is my code:

```
    def refresh_listdata(self, listdata):

        import json

        # If we delete list and append nothing appears (garbage collecctor).
        # listdata = []

        listdata *= 0   # https://stackoverflow.com/a/44349418/6929343

        bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        print ('\n=============   System services   =================\n')

        for service in dbus.SystemBus().list_names():
            # Skip over ":1.20", ":1.65", etc.
            if not service.startswith(":") :
                # print(service)
                object_path=service.replace(".", "/")
                object_path = "/" + object_path
                dictionary = self.rec_intro(bus, service, object_path)
                # print(dictionary)
                if dictionary != False :
                    listdata.append(dictionary)

        bus = dbus.SessionBus()
        print ('\n==============   Session services   ================\n')

        for service in dbus.SessionBus().list_names():
            if not service.startswith(":") :
                # print(service)
                object_path=service.replace(".", "/")
                object_path = "/" + object_path
                dictionary = self.rec_intro(bus, service, object_path)
                # print(dictionary)
                if dictionary != False :
                    listdata.append(dictionary)

#        print ("\nlistdata[0]\n", listdata[0])
#        print(json.dumps(listdata[0], indent=4, sort_keys=True))

    def rec_intro(self, bus, service, object_path, 
                       paths=None, serviceDict=None):

        from xml.etree import ElementTree

        #print(object_path)
        if paths == None:
            paths = {}
        paths[object_path] = {}

        if "-" in object_path :
            print ("Object path: '" + object_path + \
            "' contains invalid character '-'")
            return False

        try:
            obj = bus.get_object(service, object_path)
        except:
            print('Cannot get object: ', service, object_path)
            return False

        try:
            iface = dbus.Interface(obj, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable')
        except:
            print('Interface error:', obj)
            return False

        try:
            xml_string = iface.Introspect()
#        except DBusException as err:
#            # NOT DEFINED!
#            print('\nDBusException:', service)
#            print(err.message+'\n')
#            return False
        except dbus.proxies as err:
            print('\ndbus.proxies:Introspect error:', service)
            print(err.message+'\n')
            return False
#        except org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied as err:
#            # NOT DEFINED!
#            print('\norg.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied:', service)
#            print(err.message)
#            return False
        except dbus.exceptions.DBusException as err:
            # Same as dbus.DBusException
            print('\ndbus.exceptions.DBusException:', service)
            print(err.message+'\n')
            return False
        except dbus.DBusException as err:
            # Same as dbus.exceptions.DBusException
            print('\ndbus.DBusException:', service)
            print(err.message+'\n')
            return False
        except:
            print('No permissions to:', bus, service, object_path)
            return False

        for child in ElementTree.fromstring(xml_string):
            if child.tag == 'node':
                if object_path == '/':
                    object_path = ''
                new_path = '/'.join((object_path,
                                     child.attrib['name']))
                self.rec_intro(bus, service, new_path)
            else:
                if object_path == "":
                    object_path = "/"
                functiondict = {}
                paths[object_path][child.attrib["name"]] = functiondict
                for func in child.getchildren():
                    if func.tag not in functiondict.keys():
                        functiondict[func.tag] = []
                    functiondict[func.tag].append(func.attrib["name"])

        if serviceDict == None:
            serviceDict = {}
        serviceDict[service] = paths
        return serviceDict
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I'm not the first to encounter this problem due to "design flaw" of dbus over systemd. The solution was this routine:

```
    def BuildNoPermissions(self, bus):
        ''' Errors add 5 seconds:

        ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.4:/org/freedesktop/thermald:
        dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied:

        Trap this error by first:
        Build list of objects with no introspection.

        Add to list if entry:
            <policy context="default">
                <deny own="fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant"/>
                <deny own="fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1"/>
            </policy>
        ...exists. Add each deny entry to list to trap error:
        ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.19:/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1 ...

        Then before introspecting dbus make sure item isn't on list. If it is
        on list then create necessary "No permissions" entry instead.

        Now all that is left is:

        ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.1450:/org/freedesktop/
        NetworkManager/dnsmasq:

        Found in:
        /etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf:
                        <deny own="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq"/>

        Problem is NetworkManager has Introspect but denies dnsmasq so check
        deny for all *.conf files even ones with introspect.

        NOTE: when running with sudo things get worse:

        ERROR:dbus.proxies:Introspect error on :1.19:/fi/epitest/hostap/
        WPASupplicant/Interfaces/62: dbus.exceptions.DBusException:
        org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected 
        from message bus without replying

        ... and then Ubuntu prints system crash message with option to report.
        '''
#        print ('\n=============   BuildNoPermissions   =================\n')
#        print (bus, '\n')
        result = os.popen("grep -Li introspect /etc/dbus-1/system.d/*"). \
                          read().splitlines()

        for line in result:
            base=os.path.basename(line)     # remove path prefix
            base=os.path.splitext(base)[0]  # remove extension suffix
            ''' Must open up file to see if <deny> is used and add them
            '''
#            print (base)
            self.NoPermissions.append(base)

        result = os.popen("grep 'deny own' /etc/dbus-1/system.d/*"). \
                          read().splitlines()
        for deny in result:
            # [1::2] is a slicing which extracts odd values
            d = deny.split('"')[1::2]
            self.NoPermissions.append(d[0])
            # Only 1 per line, so take index 0
            # print (d[0])
```

Sorry for all the comments but it seems better to leave them in place than to delete them (or worse yet rewrite them).

To call the routine the original function was modified:

```
        bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        self.BuildNoPermissions(bus)
#        print ('\n=============   System services   =================\n')
#        print (self.NoPermissions, '\n')
        for service in bus.list_names():
            # Skip over ":1.20", ":1.65", etc.
            if not service.startswith(":") :
                denied = False
                for deny in self.NoPermissions:
                    if deny == service:
                        denied = True
                        break
                if denied: continue

                # print(service)
                object_path=service.replace(".", "/")
                object_path = "/" + object_path
                dictionary = self.rec_intro(bus, service, object_path)
                # print(dictionary)
                if dictionary != False :
                    listdata.append(dictionary)
```

Bonus answer... strip `-` out of object path names:

```
    if "-" in object_path :
        # Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1449722
        object_path = object_path.replace("-", "")
```